# regexp_replace replace every piece in text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have string like this: `aa/ss/[img]aa/ss/dd[/img][img]aa/ss/dd[/img]aa/ss`

I need replace this piece `/ss/` with this: `/WW/` but only when they are between `[img]` tags. result must be:

`aa/ss/[img]aa/WW/dd[/img][img]aa/WW/dd[/img]aa/ss`

I am trying this:

`select regexp_replace('aa/ss/[img]aa/ss/dd[/img][img]aa/ss/dd[/img]aa/ss', '(\[img\].*/)ss(/.*\[\/img\])', '\1WW\2', 'g')`

But this replaces just one piece, not both. I use `'g'` flag buth same result.

How to do this correctly ?

Comment: HTML and regular expressions ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the "greediness" of the operators.  You have repeated expressions so either `ss` could match the pattern once or twice -- depending on whether the middle `'[/img][img]` is counted as the match to the `.*` or to the fixed pattern.

Unfortunately, it is easier for me to diagnose the problem than fix it -- I find greediness in regular expressions to simply be confusing.  But, here is a fix for your particular string.  It just takes the `'['` character into account:

```
select regexp_replace('aa/ss/[img]aa/ss/dd[/img][img]aa/ss/dd[/img]aa/ss',
                      '(\[img\][^[]*/)ss(/[^[]*\[\/img\])',
                      '\1WW\2',
                      'g')
```